# How to delete buttons from a XML driven flash template from template monster?

Tags: xml, flash, templates, button

I am trying to delete some buttons from a XML driven flash template from template monster. After I delete the button from the XML file I can still see the button in flash and it has the title "Undefined".

Answer (score 0):

There might be another definition somewhere of how many buttons are expected or an array of items linked to what you deleted.

In other words if you deleted:

```
<buttonname>Google</buttonname>
<buttonname>Google</buttonname>
<buttonname>Google</buttonname>
```

It's possible something like this still exists somewhere:

```
<buttonlink>http://www.google.com</buttonlink>
<buttonlink>http://www.google.com</buttonlink>
<buttonlink>http://www.google.com</buttonlink>
```

There could also just be a line in the actionscript that says how many buttons to expect (This is more likely):

```
var expectedbuttons = 4;
```

Comment: If I send you the rar file with the fla and everything can you have ea look in it ?

Comment: Sure I can take a look: jeff@kilroymultimedia.com

Answer (score 0):

The point is that. You should delete the button(s) from .fla file as well.